# spring cloud Brixton.RELEASE config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Before I am working with Angel.SR3, I can start discovery and config server, and I can find config server in http://localhost:8761.
After migrate to Brixton Release, same configuration server property doesn't work any more. 
The config server application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8099

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/config
```

The bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config 

eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: ${server.port:8099} 
    metadata-map:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value} 
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
```

The discovery server application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Any one has a workable demo for the Brixton release?

Comment: the discovery server configuration application.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Brixton` not, but if it helps I have `Camden` in place: https://github.com/khauser/microservices4vaadin

From here I would say that you should move the eureka-part from the `bootstrap.yml` into the `application.yml`, but I don't know if this would help.

Comment: I tried your demo. After starting discovery server and config server, I could not find config server from http://localhost:8761/.

Comment: The startup needs some time I assume. Check the logs for registration entries or maybe also error messages.